# Customizing the redirect domain for Google sign-in

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, account

I want to change the default domain here but I don't want to show any domain I want to show only the app name is this possible?
When the user clicks on <kbd>continue with Google</kbd> an account chooser page comes up I can see an option
`Choose an account to continue to clt-360314.firebaseapp.com`

I want it like
`Choose an account to continue to "My Name"`

I have added the DNS record to hosting and also added it as an authorized domain to the Firebase console now I don't know why I took these two steps I really want help with what I need to do to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.